# Methods for increasing accuracying of a CNN for image classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm currently working on a image classification task, involving a large datasets of grayscale images of cartoons and my CNN needs to classify them. Atm my model has a test accuracy of about 88% but I know a higher accuracy is possible.

I've tried:

- improving / changing the actual model / architecture
- using different meta parameters
- different loss functions from the pytorch libraries
- a bunch of  different transforms
- different optimizes from torch.optim

I've also tried a bunch of the standard models included in torchvision.models and am still getting sub 90% accuracy on the test set.

Do I just need to keep trying the above things to squeeze out better accuracy or are there any other avenues I can try? Would really appreciate any suggestions, the only other thing I can think of would be making my own custom loss function specific for the data set but I'm not exactly sure how much that would help?

Comment: This kind of questions are off-topic, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404075/349130

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described, it sounds like it might be worth spending some time on the data preparation. [Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/best-practices-for-preparing-and-augmenting-image-data-for-convolutional-neural-networks/) is a good article on how to do that for images. Some ideas you could try are:

- Resizing all your images to a fixed size
- Subtracting mean pixel values, i.e. normalizing the dataset

I don't really know the context of what you're doing but I would also consider adding additional features that may be relevant and seeing if that helps.